# How to run Android Unit Test classes in a specific order?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, sequence

Is there a way to execute Android Unit Test classes in a specific order? I am not talking about test methods within a given test, this I know how to accomplish, but I have several .java classes with each having several test methods inside and I would like to run those classes in a specific sequence, as they depend on each other due API calls and CRUD operations.
I know Unit Tests shall not depend on each other but in my case I would need to reset the server DB and the App DB programmatically before each test, which is rather tricky to accomplish in my current configuration.
I would also not want to aggregate all my test methods into a single .java file and execute them with @FixMethodOrder, because then I will end up with an unmanageable chunk of test methods.

Comment: *I would need to reset the server DB and the App DB programmatically before each test, which is rather tricky to accomplish in my current configuration.* Why?

Comment: *I would like to run those classes in a specific sequence, as they depend on each* that is bad design, test cases should be able to run independently

Comment: @Manu - because the process of refreshing the server with new data and resetting all the necessary settings requires some manual tasks, not everything is automated and configurable via an api endpoint yet which I could call before / after each test.

Comment: @TimCastelijns - I know this theory and I stated it already in my question, but I need to test my system somehow and the tests should serve me and not the other way round. I do not see a point in redesigning my entire system just to comply with a "good design" for unit testing.